# classFactory error when using QGIS Plugin Reloader

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a QGIS plugin that loads perfectly fine when I open QGIS. I installed the "plugin reloader" plugin to facilitate development. However, when I reload the plugin via the reloader I get the following error:

> Couldn't load plugin TDGAlgorithmProviderPlugin due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

The accompanying trace is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 219, in startPlugin
>       plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'classFactory'

Is this a bug in the plugin reloader, or a problem with my plugin? Since it's loading just fine when QGIS starts I can't think of what I would need to do to make it compatible with the plugin reloader.